# iOS 6.0+ autorotation for youtube embedded video

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uiviewcontroller, autorotate

I want to only support vertical orientation throughout all the view controllers of my iOS app. However, I embed a YouTube video in one of my view controllers, and when that video is selected to take up the full screen, I want the user to be able to orient his/her phone horizontally so the video expands to take the full screen.

EDIT: I tried using the following code from [Autorotate  in iOS 6 has strange behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526054/autorotate-in-ios-6-has-strange-behaviour):

```
- (NSUInteger) application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {

return self.fullScreenVideoIsPlaying ?
    UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown :
    UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
```

}

and in my view controller that presents the `UIWebView`/YouTube frame, I have this code in my `viewDidLoad`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(windowNowVisible:)
     name:UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification
     object:self.view.window
];

- (void)windowNowVisible:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.fullScreenVideoIsPlaying = !(appDelegate.fullScreenVideoIsPlaying);
}
```

However, when the user presses done on the fullscreen YouTube video, if he/she still has the phone horizontally, then the presenting view controller also stays horizontal (I want the present view controller to be portrait). It's a race on the `fullSreenVideoIsPlaying` variable which isn't updating fast enough so that my presenting view controller is portrait.

Any feedback on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You may read - http://buddingdevelopers.com/autorotation-in-ios/    Autorotation is clearly explained here.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580753/mpmovieplayercontroller-rotating-in-full-screen-while-the-parent-view-controller

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Figured out a solution by molding together a few solutions I've found on StackOverflow.

Instead of using this notification

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
      addObserver:self
      selector:@selector(windowNowVisible:)
      name:UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification
      object:self.view.window
 ];
```

I use the following notifications

```
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(youTubeStarted:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification" object:nil];
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(youTubeFinished:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerWillExitFullscreenNotification" object:nil];
```

with the implementations

```
 -(void) youTubeStarted:(NSNotification*) notif {
     AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
     appDelegate.fullScreenVideoIsPlaying = YES;
}
 -(void) youTubeFinished:(NSNotification*) notif {
     AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
     appDelegate.fullScreenVideoIsPlaying = NO;
 }
```

and in my AppDelegate, I have

```
 - (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{
     NSUInteger orientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
     if (self.fullScreenVideoIsPlaying) {
         return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
     }
     else {        
         if(self.window.rootViewController){
             UIViewController *presentedViewController = [[(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController viewControllers] lastObject];
             orientations = [presentedViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
     }
return orientations;
 }
```

and in my view controllers, I have

```
 -(BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
     return NO;
 }
 -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
     return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
 }
 - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation{
     return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
 }
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that using private notifications (`UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification` and `UIMoviePlayerControllerWillExitFullscreenNotification`) could break in future iOS releases or cause an App Store rejection.

Comment: Ok thanks! Do you know of any other notification I could use?

Comment: Unfortunately the SDK doesn't provide any as of iOS 6.

Comment: What I ended up doing is returning UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown in the delegate method, and then subclassing UITabBarController (my root view controller) to return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait in -supportedInterfaceOrientations.  That way, video can play in landscape, but all the child view controllers of the tab bar controller only support portrait.

Comment: How can i make portrait only?

Comment: Sorry my mistake,i want landscape only for youtube player.

Comment: How'd you hook up the notifications?

Comment: Rohan:dude you are my hero...u saved my day

Comment: @jszumski's comment makes me nervous, but I have exhausted my search for better solutions.

Answer (score 6):

I've encountered the very same problem before, and the best solution I could find that worked under iOS 5.x and 6.x was to present the video controller in a modal view.

The modal view is a `UINavigationController` that wraps the video controller and responds with `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll` in `supportedInterfaceOrientations`.  In the modal view's `viewWillAppear:`, I flip `fullScreenVideoIsPlaying` to `YES` and set it to `NO` in `viewWillDisappear:`.  This arrangement will keep the underlying view controllers in portrait while allowing the modal view to rotate as the user sees fit.

Comment: thanks for your response..had a quick follow-up question. Right now, my UIWebView of the youtube video is a small cell (200x100) in the middle of my presenting view controller. When it's selected to play, how do I present the video in a modal view controller? In other words, how do I get a callback that the user pressed the play button in the UIWebView?

Comment: The video player that comes from the web view will respect its parent's rotation settings, so you'll have to make your "presenting view controller" a modal view.

Comment: I understand that the video player will respect its parent's rotation settings; however, my issue is that I don't want the present view controller to be able to rotate horizontally. Only the video player that it presents should be able to rotate horizontally

Comment: Specifically, how do you "present the video controller in a modal view"? Is there a way I can get a pointer to the video controller?

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't a way to get a reference to the web view's `MPMoviePlayerController`, I meant controller as in the view controller containing your 200x100 web view.  You could present a full-size `UIWebView` in a modal controller and have it auto play (`mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO`).

Comment: thanks this is starting to make sense to me. do you have any code that shows how to do this? My issue specifically is, how do I present a modal view that is a uinavigationcontroller that wraps the video controller? Since the youtube video is in a webview and I don't have any callbacks, I don't know when the user touches play in the webview. Also, the uiwebview of the embedded youtube video is in a uicollectionviewcell (not sure if that's relevant)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I've found a new solution which I posted here