# MPMoviePlayer Controller view should autorotate to landscape right by default

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, autorotate

I have two view controllers.One view has button, when user click on the button he will redirect to another view where MPMoviePlayer Controller is present.I want to show MPMoviePlayer controller view to LandsapeRight mode by Default.

I write the below code in buttonAction

```
-(void)buttonAction
{

    tLive = [[toneTvlive alloc]init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:tLive animated:YES];
}
```

and in the 2nd view i write the below code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    printf("\n hii");
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarHidden:NO];
    NSURL *mediaURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@""];
    mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:mediaURL];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                               object:nil];

    //[mp setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
    [mp setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming];
    [mp setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];

    [mp.view setFrame: CGRectMake(0,0, 480,320)];
    [self.view addSubview:mp.view];

    [mp prepareToPlay];
    [mp play];

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations.

    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

while run the program first it shows the view in portrait mode only.It doesn't prompt the view to rotate in landscape,but after when i rotate the device once it works fine.Can anyone please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using iOS 6+ you can autorotate the view controller to landscape:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}
```

If you're targeting earlier iOS versions, here's [a good SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5363469/394561) about the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for reply Erik.Right now i am using ios 4.2 for that any suggestion please..!