# MPMoviePlayer is not rotating

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, mpmovieplayer

In my application i have a UIWebview where I am showing a list of Video Link . Clicking on one of those links, MPMoviePlayer launches itself. But in the full screen mode its not rotating when needed.

How to rotate it now as I have no control for it in webview.

Comment: Landscape mode not working do you mean?

Comment: Yes. Video is restricted to portrait mode only

Comment: Did you try the below code? - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using IOS 6 use `- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {}`
because shouldautorotate is not any more available for ios 6.

Answer (score 0):

post this method in `AppDelegate.m`  file..

```
    -(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
    {
         return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;    
    }
```

Comment: @WakkaoW also try this answer dude.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740732/iphone-force-mpmovieplayercontroller-to-play-video-in-landscape-mode :)

Answer (score 0):

For iOS6 you should also make sure you have landscape added in your supported interface orientations key on your info.plist.